# cups-pdf prints anonymously, how to print as user?

Tags: pdf, network-printer, cups

On a RHEL 5.0, i installed cups-pdf package from epel, then i get the `Cups-PDF` printer, as indicated there http://www.commentcamarche.net/faq/32427-cups-pdf-pour-les-machines-windows (so `HP`/`HP Laserjet color PS` driver)

Samba is connected to a domain as my Windows 7 client station.  I use the connection dialog (right click on printer) to connect `Cups-PDF`, but documents still appears on the anonymous directory.

How can I make the pdf documents appears in the home directory of my non-admin user / on a directory which depends upon the connected user on Windows 7?

Thank for reading.